# Is there any limit to the number of recipients in MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone

Is there any limit to the number of recipients in MFMessageComposeViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, there is no definite limit on number of recipients in `MFMessageComposeViewController`

As you could see in the below code

**toRecipients** is an array **So** you could try with filling as many as contacts you prefer to check the limit on number of recipients ...

```
void sendSMS
{
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *myMessageComposeViewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        myMessageComposeViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        NSString *bodyString = nil;

        NSMutableArray *toRecipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [toRecipients addObject:@"0933660805"];
        [myMessageComposeViewController setRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients];
        [toRecipients release];

        bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Message body"];
        [myMessageComposeViewController setBody:bodyString];

        [self presentModalViewController:myMessageComposeViewController animated:YES];
        [myMessageComposeViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-SW7), there is no such limit on the number of recipients.